# How to determine the error in the kinetic energy of a body when error in it's momentum is given?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, error-analysis

this is a question from my text book and I tried solving it with the various cases mentioned in the book (such as, if X=m+v then, deltaX = delta m+delta v) but I could not.

Comment: So what did you try? I presume you know the formula for kinetic energy as a function of momentum?

Comment: is only error in momentum given or momentum and kinetic energy too

Comment: I don't see what x=m+v means.

Comment: I tried by writing E(k) as square of momentum / velocity but that clearly didn't help and I also tried to differentiate KE wrt vellocity and found out that : d/dv(KE) = momentum but  I couldn't work it out further

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy as a function of the momentum is 
\begin{align}
T = \frac{|\vec{p}|^2}{2m}
\end{align}
So if we have an error in measuring $|\vec{p}|=p$ of $\Delta p$, we just want to use the Gaußian way of propagation of uncertainty:

\begin{align}
\Delta T &= \left|\frac{\partial T}{\partial p} \right| \Delta p \\
&= \left|\frac{p}{m} \right| \Delta p
\end{align}

So if you know the margin of error for your momentum, then you can translate it to the margin of error for your kinetic energy via this formula.

For more insights see maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty